# How to change place for index.html in Spring-Boot Maven project

Tags: maven, spring-boot

For my Spring boot and maven project, I need to customize the static resources folder structure.

Generally, the index.html is at location **src/main/webapp**

i.e.

```
Project
       |
        src
           |
            main
                |
                 webapp
                       |
                        index.html
```

I need it like

```
Project
       |
        src
       |   |
       |    main
       |        |
       |        webapp
       |              
       index.html
```

i.e. I need Index.html to be placed directly under **project folder**

Is there any way to achieve it??

Comment: It seems strange .why you need this ?

Comment: I am using an internal ui framework based on angular js. This framework needs the index.html file to be directly under the project root folder....

can we do this??

Answer (score 0):

try to create this bean and point to index.html that you make wherever you want

```
 @Bean
  public InternalResourceViewResolver getViewResolver() {
    InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
    viewResolver.setPrefix("path to file");
    viewResolver.setSuffix(".html");
  return viewResolver;
  }
```

then you will go to how to make index.html as a default page

```
@Override
public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
   registry.addViewController("/").setViewName("index");
}
```

i hope my answer helps you

Comment: This helps only when the path of the file exists withi webapp folder..

My file needs to be at project root location.....     can you please tell me how to give path of that?

Comment: you can use  ../ get you path left step and ../.. two steps left  .